# Brushes to Colors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba

Hey I was doing a VisualBasic Windows Form Control project and I encountered with an little issue:

This is my OnPaint Method:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        Dim g As Graphics
        g = e.Graphics
        Dim ancho As Integer = Me.Width / 2
        Dim alto As Integer = Me.Height / 2
        _posiciox = 5
        Percentatge(_maxim,_minim)
        For Index As Double = 0.1 To 10.0
            If Index <= _percent Then
                If Index >= 9 Then
                    g.FillRectangle(_color4, _posiciox, alto - 10, 40, 20)
                ElseIf Index >= 8 Then
                    g.FillRectangle(_color3, _posiciox, alto - 10, 40, 20)
                ElseIf Index >= 6 Then

                    g.FillRectangle(_color2, _posiciox, alto - 10, 40, 20)
                Else
                    g.FillRectangle(_color1, _posiciox, alto - 10, 40, 20)
                End If
            End If
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, _posiciox, alto - 10, 40, 20)
            _posiciox = _posiciox + 45
        Next
    End Sub
```

Where the color Filled are Brushes.Color params. Also I wanted to let the User chose this Color.

I've tried with Public property like this:

```
Public Property ColorBaix() As Color
        Get
            Return Color.Coral
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
        End Set
    End Property
```

But I can't transform a Brushes.Color into a Color.Color:

I've found some examples [Colors to Brush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183856/converting-from-a-color-to-a-brush) but I can't use "new param" on OnPaint due to overloading issues.

- **Is It that the Only way or Maybe there is another solution?**

SOLVED:

I adapted my project:

```
<Description("Color Primari")>
    Public Property ColorBaix() As Color
        Get
            Return color1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            color1 = value
            _color1 = New SolidBrush(value)
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're barking up the wrong tree a bit.

You don't want to turn a brush into a colour, you want to set the color property of your existing brush to a new value.

so when you first made the brush you did something like this:

```
        Dim mybrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Aqua)
```

then later you want to set the colour

```
    mybrush.Color = Color.Azure
```

if you want to obtain the colour of a brush, then you can do this:

```
       Dim myColour As New Color

    myColour = mybrush.Color
```

Comment: Thanks that help me a lot, i adapted my project to what you post.